# Multiple cell selection with search

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've created a `UITableView` which contains a list of teams which all have a accessoryView. This accessoryView indicates whether a cell is selected or not. Each cell is connected with a custom Object in my `Team` class.

When a cell is selected it then saves the particular team Object in a teamSelected array.

All this works fine. However there seem to be a issue when search and then filter the data and select a cell it seem to add the wrong object and change the accessoryView on a wrong object to?

How come it does to not add the correct object on cell selection when the searchBar is active?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("teamCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeamCell

    if (self.teamSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row].name

    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.teamArray[indexPath.row].name as String
    }

    let team = self.teamArray[indexPath.row] as Team
    var removed = false

    for (index, value) in enumerate(self.teamSelected) {
        if (value.id == team.id) {

            cell.accessoryView = cell.accessoryCheck
            removed = true
        }
    }

    if (!removed) {
        cell.accessoryView = cell.accessoryUncheck
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if (self.teamSearchController.active) {
        team = self.filteredTableData[indexPath.row] as! Team
        removed = false
    } else {
        team = self.teamArray[indexPath.row] as Team
        removed = false
    }

    for (index, value) in enumerate(self.teamSelected) {
        if (value.id == team.id) {
            self.teamSelected.removeAtIndex(index)
            removed = true
        }
    }

    if (!removed) {
        self.teamSelected.append(team)
    }

    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.teamSelected)
    userDefaults.setObject(encodedData, forKey: "teams")
    userDefaults.synchronize()

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: There is a strange moment in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:
in one branch of if you use `as!` operator, and `as` in another.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in objective c. I have also used uisearchview Controller. I have use this code. cellSelected is a nsmutable array. Use this code in didSelect method of table View.

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
       {

```
       if ([self.cellSelected containsObject:[self.searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"id"]])
       {
           [self.cellSelected removeObject:[self.searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"id"]];


       }
       else
       {
        [self.cellSelected addObject:[self.searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"id"]];

               [self.selectedCategoryArray addObject:getSelectedCategory];   
       }
   }
```

after this use this code in cellforrowatindexpath method

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
   {
       NSLog(@"self.searchArray..%@",self.searchArray);
       titleName.text = [self.searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"name"];
       if ([self.cellSelected containsObject:[self.searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"id"]])
       {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
       }
       else
       {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       }
   }
```

In the above code make else and use your actual array. hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: The difference is i use a custom Object and you don't therefor i cant use containsObject